# Gunicorn With Gevent, Performance Gain

Tags: python, gunicorn, gevent

**Gunicorn Worker Class**

Gunicorn has worker_class setting. Some possible values are

- sync
- gthread
- gevent

[Definitions from Luis Sena's nice blog](https://dev.to/lsena/gunicorn-worker-types-how-to-choose-the-right-one-4n2c)

**sync**
This is the default worker class. Each process will handle 1 request at a time and you can use the parameter -w to set workers.

The recommendation for the number of workers is 2–4 x $(NUM_CORES), although it will depend on how your application works.

**gthread**
If you use gthread, Gunicorn will allow each worker to have multiple threads. In this case, the Python application is loaded once per worker, and each of the threads spawned by the same worker shares the same memory space.

Those threads will be at the mercy of the GIL, but it’s still useful for when you have some I/O blocking happening. It will allow you to handle more concurrency without increasing your memory too much.

**gevent**
Eventlet and gevent make use of “green threads” or “pseudo threads” and are based on greenlet.

In practice, if your application work is mainly I/O bound, it will allow it to scale to potentially thousands of concurrent requests on a single process.

Even with the rise of async frameworks (fastapi, sanic, etc), this is still relevant today since it allows you to optimize for I/O without having the extra code complexity.

The way they manage to do it is by “monkey patching” your code, mainly replacing blocking parts with compatible cooperative counterparts from gevent package.

It uses epoll or kqueue or libevent for highly scalable non-blocking I/O. Coroutines ensure that the developer uses a blocking style of programming that is similar to threading, but provide the benefits of non-blocking I/O.

This is usually the most efficient way to run your django/flask/etc web application, since most of the time the bulk of the latency comes from I/O related work.

**Workers Value**

While using gevent workers threads count is not set up. Documentation [settings - threads](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html) says that threads are only relevant for gthread workers. So with gevent we only have workers. And each worker is a separate operating system process as far as I know. And the workers count is 8 to 16 for a 4 core machine.

**Where does the performance gain come from**

So really there is not any threads executed? If there is not any threads how does the gevent workers gain performance. There should be some pseudo threads that should be executed concurrently. While some pseudo thread is making I/O it should be detected and another pseudo thread should be executed. So where is this another pseudo thread? Is it the other worker processes or gunicorn creates some pseudo threads within a worker process?

Comment: One request becomes one greenlet. The greenlets are spread over the processes.

Comment: @KlausD. so there is no limit to the concurrent requests. Probably with round robin each request is spread to a new process. If worker_count=5 and we have 100 request each worker will have 20 greenlet.

Answer (score -1):

> **The performance gain comes from the use of "greenlets" or "pseudo threads" provided by "gevent" library**

- **Concurrency:** "gevent" uses lightweight units called "greenlets" to handle concurrency.
- **EventLoop:** this allows greenlets to switch between each other during I/O operations, this prevents one operation from blocking the entire process.
- **No Threads, Separate Processes:** there are no threads within each worker process. Each worker process operates independently, running its own set of greenlets.

I hope this clears your doubts!! Keep Coding!!